# How to remove Thread from ConcurrentDictionary<int, Thread> when Thread completes

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, windows-services

Here are my project requirements:

1. A Windows Service that hosts a WCF service.
2. The WCF service must initiate and keep track of many threads.
3. Each thread must be identifiable by a provided key.
4. There will be many different types of tasks (threads), each with a "maximum running at a time" limit with the additional tasks in a queue until others of same type finish.

What I have so far:

1. A Windows Service that hosts a WCF service (similar to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069(v=vs.110).aspx).
2. An abstract class containing a Thread (using composition because I cannot extend Thread)
3. Inside the WCF service class, I have a static instance of a class named MyThreadPool containing a ConcurrentDictionary that keeps record of my running threads.

My questions are:

1. What is the best way to remove the completed threads from the thread list (on completion of the thread)?
2. In this scenario, is a static instance of a ConcurrentDictionary a good method to manage threads? If not, what could be recommended?

Some of my code is shown below:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "...")]
public interface IMyService    
{
    [OperationContract]
    void StartProcess(int MIndexId, int MProcessId);
    [OperationContract]
    void StopProcess(int MIndexProcessId);
}

public class MyService : IMyService
{
    private static MyThreadPool threadPool = new MyThreadPool();

    public void StopProcess(int MIndexProcessId)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void StartProcess(int ItemIdToProcess, int ProcessTypeId)
    {
        // call threadPool.LaunchThread(...)
    }
}

public class MyThreadPool
{
    private ConcurrentDictionary<int, BaseThread> _threads;
    ...
    public void LaunchThread(BaseThread thread, int ItemIdToProcess)
    {
        // set additional data for thread (such as a key and name) for tracking in a database
        _threads.AddOrUpdate(ItemIdToProcess, thread, (key, oldValue) => { return      oldValue; });
        thread.Start();
    }
    public void KillThread(int ItemIdToProcess)
    { 
        ...
    }
}

public abstract class BaseThread
{
    // some additional properties for tracking thread
    // ...
    private Thread _thread;

    protected BaseThread()
    { 
        _thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.RunThread));
        _thread.IsBackground = true;
    }
    // Thread methods / properties
    public void Start() { _thread.Start(); }
    public void Join() { _thread.Join(); }
    public bool IsAlive { get { return _thread.IsAlive; } }
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _thread.Name;
        }
        set
        {
            _thread.Name = value;
        }
    }
    public void Abort()
    {
        _thread.Abort();
    }
    public abstract void RunThread();
}

public class ValidateThread : BaseThread
{
    public override void RunThread()
    {
        ...
        // indicate to calling thread to remove from thread list();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have answered your questions. Any more specific concerns I should address?

Comment: In general, it's not a very good idea to write your own ThreadPool unless you have very specific requirements not covered by WCF threading capabilities. See this question answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295045/does-wcf-support-multi-threading-itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Make the thread remove itself after it has done all meaningful work. Better yet, use `Task` with the `LongRunning` option. Composing tasks is easy.
2. Seems reasonable. You have avoided a lot of pitfalls already and the design seems solid. One pitfall with WCF services hosted in IIS is that worker processes can die at any time. You avoid that by using a Windows Service.

A Windows Service is mostly an externally started exe like any other.

One thing that is not ok, though, is: `_thread.Abort();` [Thread.Abort is evil](https://www.google.com/webhp?complete=1&hl=en#complete=1&hl=en&q=thread.abort%20evil). Cancellation *must* (not: should) be cooperative in .NET.

Comment: Thanks. My WCF service is not hosted in IIS. It is hosted in a Windows Service. How would I "make the thread remove itself" from the specific thread? Should I pass a reference of the ConcurrentDictionary to each thread and then remove from the ConcurrentDictionary from that thread?

Comment: Yes. If architecture requires it, you can give the thread a callback to call when it has completed its work. That way the thread does not need to know anything about the central registry.; Or, if you're using tasks, attach a continuation. That way the main task does not need to know anything about the central registry.